# Keras 2.0.3 compatibility

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, keras

Is keras 2.0.3 (latest version) compatible with latest Anaconda version (4.3.1, python version 3.6) ? Or keras is only compatible with python 3.5, so I must choose older version of Anaconda?

EDIT: I have some problems when I use this method:

```
prediction = np_utils.categorical_probas_to_classes(prediction)
```

Error: "keras.utilis.np_utilis" has no attribute "categorical_probas_to_classes"

Also I have other errors with keras's methods. So I thought that problem is python version, that is incompatible with keras's version

Comment: What makes you think it may be incompatible? Or what about, like, just trying it out?

Comment: This kind of questions makes me think you have some underlying problem that you are not telling us about, how about more information?

Comment: I added some new information

Comment: categorical_probas_to_classes was removed from Keras a long time ago, your problem is that you are just using outdated code.

Comment: Do you know any similar method? I can't find updated tutorial about keras,  this is why I used that method. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

At least on Windows, Tensorflow wants Python 3.5. You can easily change your Python version without reinstalling Anaconda; you just create a new conda environment:

```
    conda create -n myenv python=3.5 anaconda
    activate myenv
    (myenv) pip install tensorflow
    (myenv) conda install keras
```

That said, keras.np_utils does not have the function you describe, regardless of Python version. And as it seems that you can already import some Keras functions, it is more likely that you need to adjust your code to the Keras 2 API than that you have a problem with your Python version.

Answer (score 0):

if you used activation="softmax", 
use:

```
prediction = model.predict(x_test)
prediction = ***prediction.round(0)***
print(prediction[:15])
```